# MYSQL generate consecutive numbers from range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Table

classRoom

```
id  class   no_of_seats start_seat_no   end_seat_no
1   A1      3           105             107
2   A2      2           108             109
3   A3      2           110             111
```

i want to insert data in the table 
**seat_records**
like this

```
id  class   seat_no
1   A1      105
2   A1      106
3   A1      107
4   A2      108
5   A2      109
6   A3      110
7   A3      111
8   A3      112
```

tried doing everything given in previous questions, but failed.

```
SELECT 'A1' class, 105 start_seat_no, 107 end_seat_no
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A2',108,109
From classRoom
```

Comment: What have you tried, This seems to be fairly simple if your columns are nullable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a source of integers to do a join.  If you have enough rows, you can use the same table and variables:

```
insert into seat_records(class, seat_no)
    select class, cr.start_seat_no + n.n - 1
    from ClassRoom cr join
         (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
          from ClassRoom cross join
               (select @rn := 0) vars
         ) n
         on cr.start_seat_no + n.n - 1 <= cr.end_seat_no;
```

You should add the `id` itself as an auto-incrementing column.  That way, it will be set on input.  If you really want to set it on input, you can also use variables:

```
insert into seat_records(id, class, seat_no)
    select @id := @id + 1, class, cr.start_seat_no + n.n - 1
    from ClassRoom cr join
         (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
          from ClassRoom cross join
               (select @rn := 0) vars
         ) n
         on cr.start_seat_no + n.n - 1 <= cr.end_seat_no cross join
         (select @id := 0) vars
```

Comment: Works very well thanks!  But fails to where start_seat_no is varchar. How can this be sorted out.

Comment: If `end_seat_no-start_seat_no` is greater than the number of rows in `ClassRoom` will the inner `select @rn ...` generate enough numbers? (it seems to me it will not...)

Comment: I suppose you could add more cross joins against `ClassRoom` or some other table, but I wonder if you know a better way.